# Save post edits keyboard shortcut?

Tags: feature-request, edits

Editing a lot of post lately, and having to go all the way down to the bottom of the page to click **"Save"**. Especially when done editing code, I have to use the mouse or <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to lose the edit area focus.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for saving post edits?

Comment: There is no other option, no keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank your for your answer. Don't you think there should be?

Comment: @KobyDouek probably not considering that you could accidentally hit Ctrl + S (as an example) when you actually meant to hit Shift + S and then boo you've saved an edit that hasn't been finished. Hitting the button is a confirmed action.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree ctrl + something is prblematic, but maybe other key combinations? Maybe ctrl+shift+s ?